# UIBarButtonItem setTintColor doesn't work for dark colors

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikit, uibarbuttonitem

I am setting the `tintColor` of a `UIBarButtonItem`. This works as long as the color is a bright color, as soon as I try to set it to `darkGrayColor` nothing happens, in fact it changes the tint to white!  But if I change the color to `redColor` then it works... What is going on here?

```
UIBarButtonItem *penButton = [_toolBar.items objectAtIndex:3];
UIBarButtonItem *crossButton = [_toolBar.items objectAtIndex:4];

//This actually sets the tint to white not gray, which is odd?
[penButton setTintColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]]; 
[crossButton setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]]; //Red is fine, as is green etc
```

Comment: Have you tried supplying a custom color (RGB-values) and checked the results?

Comment: Good idea but that doesnt seem to work either, I'll update question with results

Comment: Setting the tint color didnt work but setting a new alpha did!!

Comment: setting a new alpha of the entire `UIBarButtonItem` or of the color value supplied with the tint color? In any case I would suggest you to create a bug report as such restrictions do not seem to be documented. Keep us posted plz.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `[UIColor redColor]` and `[UIColor darkGrayColor]` is that the former is set using RGB values and the latter with a grayscale, and the `UIBarButtonItem` is somehow ignoring the grayscale. You can test this theory by comparing:

```
[penButton setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:1.0]]; 

[penButton setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.5 alpha:1.0]];
```

If the former is as expected but the latter is not, then the problem is indeed with grayscale. Otherwise I have no idea what's causing this behavior.

Comment: I tried that and it still came out as white, setting the alpha to 0.2 got the effect I wanted but obviously leave the original question unanswered!

Comment: @Chris Interesting. Do you mean you set the alpha of the `UIColor` or of the `UIBarButtonItem`?

Comment: I meant the alpha of the UIColor as per your example!